# An inequality for real numbers

Tags: inequalities

I need to prove the following inequality.

For every $a,b,x,y \in [0,1]$, it holds that:

$abx + (1-a)(1-b)y \leq \left( a^2b^2x^4 + (1-a)^2(1-b)^2y^4 \right)^{1/4}$

I don't know if this is correct but I checked via a computer that it holds for all $a,b,x,y \in \{\frac{k}{100} : 0 \leq k \leq 100\}$.

Comment: It suffices to show that $$ S = a^{2/3}b^{2/3} + (1-a)^{2/3} (1-b)^{2/3} \leq 1$$ after applying Holder. Applying Cauchy you get $$ S^2 \leq (a^{4/3} + (1-a)^{4/3})(b^{4/3} + (1-b)^{4/3}) $$ which $\leq 1$ by elementary arguments.

Answer (score 1):

By the generalization of Hölder's inequality, i.e.
$$
(u_1v_1w_1z_1+u_2v_2w_2z_2)^4\leq (u_1^4+u_2^4)\dots(z_1^4+z_2^4)
$$
and $ab+(1-a)(1-b)\leq 1$ we have
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&(abx+(1-a)(1-b)y)^4\\ 
&\leq&\left(a^2b^2x^4+(1-a)^2(1-b)^2y^4\right) (a+(1-a))(b+(1-b))(ab+(1-a)(1-b))\\
&\leq& a^2b^2x^4+(1-a)^2(1-b)^2y^4.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$